# Provided element is not within a Document - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, html2canvas

I am trying to send HTML invoices to users as Image.

For that purpose i am using html2canvas library, but it is continuously giving me error:

> Provided element is not within a Document

Here is what i am trying to do in componentDidMount()

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('invoice'), {
        logging: true,
        profile: true,
        useCORS: true}).then(function(canvas) {
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9);
    var src = encodeURI(data);
    console.log(src);
});
```

And **invoice** element do exist in DOM.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try to capture the element with [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

So your component will look like this:

```
class Invoice extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        html2canvas(this.invoice, {
                logging: true,
                profile: true,
                useCORS: true}).then(function(canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9);
            var src = encodeURI(data);
            console.log(src);
        });
    }
    render(){
        return <div ref={r => this.invoice = r}>....</div>
    }
}
```